# Unable to add Json.Net to Portable Class Library with MonoDroid and MonoTouch

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, json.net, mvvmcross

I don't understand this post -  http://slodge.blogspot.co.uk/2013/01/almost-portable-binaries.html

I'm still slightly confused. Are you saying that if we choose to use something like Json.Net in our app, we need to use a version specifically for MonoDroid and another specifically for MonoTouch? Currently, I have a Portable Class Library that contains my view models. My view models rely on Json.

When I attempt to manually add a reference to the NewtonSoft library included with MvvmCross, I get a compile-time error that says: "The type or namespace name 'Newtonsoft' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

If I attempt to add Json.Net via NuGet, I receive an error that says: "Successfully installed 'Newtonsoft.Json 5.0.3'.
Successfully uninstalled 'Newtonsoft.Json 5.0.3'.
Install failed. Rolling back...
Could not install package 'Newtonsoft.Json 5.0.3'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'portable-win+net45+MonoAndroid16+sl40+net10+wp71', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author."

What is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The situation with PCLs inside the xamarin products is rapidly evolving - proper pcl support should be available within a few weeks, and there are also big mono2->mono3 changes occurring.

Until these changes are a bit more complete, the situation is:

- you will probably be able to use existing profile 2 and profile 104 PCLs on droid as binaries
- you may get away with using PCL binaries on iOS - but it's less likely
- it is safest to rebuild your PCLs for each platform

Specifically for json.net I have bundled a version with mvx for several months and not had a problem on iOS or touch, but I have not used every option and code path - so there may be gremlins lurking in this approach.

---

For nuget support for droid and touch, dsplaisted added this to nuget 2.5 (a hero!) - but so far the only package author i know who has added support for xamarin nuget targets is me - please do encourage other authors to join in - maybe by sending them a pull request?

Comment: Thank you Stuart. Just out of curiosity, where do you read about the changes between mono2 -> mono3? Thank you.

Comment: Not really - but mt jumps from .net2 to .net4.5 - which is a big jump