# Get/change MonoTouch Framework Version

Tags: .net, xamarin.ios, xamarin

After months of development I've stucked with a ridiculus problem. I want to know, what exact framework version of mt is installed on my machine or referenced in a project. If I type

```
cat /Developer/MonoTouch/Version
```

on a MAC terminal, it will see

```
7.0.4.209
```

If I look into the result of

```
var version = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().ImageRuntimeVersion;
```

in my project I'll get

```
v2.0.50727
```

This is the same version as some of my libs (for example System.Core).

But isn't a newer mt-Framework available? I even tried to reinstall MT on my Mac but It claims that everything is up to date.

Background: I've got the same problem as is described in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16120713/unable-to-add-json-net-to-portable-class-library-with-monodroid-and-monotouch) using JSON.NET in conjunction with PCL and Nuget. The answer there states that those problems should disappear with mt3. So how can I switch to version 3?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But isn't a newer mt-Framework available?

No.

> I even tried to reinstall MT on my Mac but It claims that everything is up to date.

It is up to date. 7.0.4 is the latest stable release at this date (Dec. 18th 2013).

Now you are mixing several things:

**Mono version**

Xamarin.iOS version 6.2 and earlier (down to 4.0) used Mono 2.10. Xamarin.iOS 6.4 (and later) uses Mono 3.0 (or 3.2). That's the **"3"** the [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16120713/unable-to-add-json-net-to-portable-class-library-with-monodroid-and-monotouch) was referring to.

**Xamarin.iOS version**

The version of XI is available, at runtime, using:

```
string version = MonoTouch.Constants.Version;
```

and that will give you something like: `"7.0.4"` (latest stable release).

**CLR version**

Using [`ImageRuntimeVersion`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.imageruntimeversion%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) the version of the common language runtime (CLR) *needed* to execute the assembly. That's not very important in an iOS-only context.

**Assembly version**

You could get version of the assemblies but again that won't help you much (because it's part of the assembly strongname and they won't be updated to maintain compatibility).

**PCL**

Full PCL support is [very recen](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2013/11/13/pcl-and-net-nuget-libraries-are-now-enabled-for-xamarin.aspx)t and you'll need the latest Mono (not only Xamarin.iOS) version to have it work properly.

Comment: Thanks a lot for clearification. So I understand, that I have to take care of latest Mono by myself. Is there some form of automatic update by shell or do I have to download this manually?

Comment: @sprinter252 Mono comes as part of the X.iOS installer. You don't need to install anything else manually.

Comment: The **initial** installer will install everything you need (and the latest version of the software). However it's possible, when updating, to mix versions (or only update some software) even if the UI *encourage* you not to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to poupou for his excellent answer. In my case this didn't resolve the problem, that I got an MT2002 every time I tried to build for the iOS-Device. Finally after hours of tries I got it to work.

I recorgnized, that Json.Net don't brings the right subset into PCL. They will be installed but the only PCL-compliant sets they bring (current version is 5.0.8) are:

- portable-net40+sl4+wp7+win8
- portable-net45+wp80+win8

As you can see, monotouch isn't included here. The problem now is, that those libs will reference System.Dynamic.Runtime, which will crash on Device-build as poupou explained.

Solution: 
I used the Json.Net-version from the [Xamarin component store](http://components.xamarin.com/gettingstarted/json.net). If you are installing or updating nugets which reference nuget, you have to remove their Json.Net afterwards and replace it with this version.